# How do I determine if a write succeeded with amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If I do a putItem() which returns a result structure, how do I determine if the write succeeded or failed?

Comment: Are you working with a particular language, or directly with their REST interface?  In Java, it you receive a Result structure, then the PutItem succeeded.  If it failed, the client call would throw an Exception.

Comment: Right now I'm playing with the PHP SDK but I was looking at Java also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS RESTful API is using HTTP status codes for identification of problems. [`PutItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) returns HTTP code 200 if your item was accepted by DynamoDB for writing. All APIs (incl. PHP and Java) parse these codes and throw exceptions if it's not 200.

Keep in mind, that code 200 doesn't mean that you can immediately read this item from DynamoDB. It only means that it's accepted for writing. Read more about DynamoDB [consistency models](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#What_is_the_consistency_model_of_Amazon_DynamoDB).